# Expected hitting time of one barriers

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk

I have learned the skill to deal with [Expected hitting time of one of two barriers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342653/expected-hitting-time-of-one-of-two-barriers).

Now I have a similar one.The walker starts from x=0 and the barriers are located in x=+n.The walker can move one step on the right with probability p and one step on the left with probability q **except at point x=0**.At x=0,walker move one step on the right with p and stay on the same place with q.Now how to compute $E_n$?

$E_{n}$ represents expected hitting time from x=0 to x=n.$E_{i->j}$represents expected hitting time from x=i to x=j.

I conclude $E_n=E_{n-1}+1+q E_{(n-2->n)}$,$E_{n-2->n}=E_{n}-E_{n-2}$.
Then I can get an iteration: $(1-q)E_{n}=E_{n-1}-qE_{n-2}+1$.I can solve it with above skill.

But I can't prove $E_{n-2->n}=E_{n}-E_{n-2}$.Can any one prove it right or wrong?

Comment: I *think* I know what $E_n$ is, but $E_{(n-2->n)}$?

Comment: Furthermore, [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/342681/) fully applies.

Comment: @Did I edit what does E(n−2−>n) means.

Comment: You "can't prove (that) $E_{n-2->n}=E_{n}-E_{n-2}$" but perhaps you can prove that $E_n=E_{n-2}+E_{n-2->n}$.